# how to fetch value with jquery

Tags: jquery

```
<div>
<select id="accountSelect" style="display: inline-block;">
<option value="a1-rBDwfPgoJtZAz1cyXo51G0gWIGn9e"> 
</option>
<option value="a1-St0wObmsmwxBcqgEl2XWhGEgjGWkE"> 
</option>
</select>
</div>
```

With jquery I need to get the value of the first token i.e
a1-rBDwfPgoJtZAz1cyXo51G0gWIGn9e
and store it in a variable
How do I do that? I thought till here

```
$(#header .right-header #accountSelect)
```

That will reach me till account select but how to fetch the fist value? Do I need to add another id in the option tag where the tokens are or It can still be fetched

Comment: you want to store it in a javascript variable?

Answer (score 1):

To fetch first value you can simply do;

```
var val = $("#accountSelect option:first").val();
```

To fetch value of `n`th option :

```
var val = $("#accountSelect option:eq(n)").val();  //just replace n with your desired element. Index starting from 0. So for 1st element replace n with 0.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#accountSelect").val($("#accountSelect option:first").val());
```

It will give you the first value of drop down

Comment: Sorry for confusing with $(#header .right-header #accountSelect) there were other tags too

Answer (score 0):

You can find **first option** as below:

```
$("#accountSelect")[0][0].value
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
    $("#accountSelect").find('option[value="a1-rBDwfPgoJtZAz1cyXo51G0gWIGn9e"]').attr('selected','selected');
    var val = $("#accountSelect").val();
```